# Вытаскиваем url, на котором я сейчас нахожусь

Tags: url, php

Как сделать проверку, если в url, на котором я нахожусь, есть слово id и рядом какая-та цифра, то делаем одно, иначе ничего не делаем?

Answer (score 6):

1) Если запрос отправлен формой или записан в стандартном виде (`www.mysite.ru/page.php?name=Alexey&surname=Bogolyubskiy&something=123123`), то значение каждой такой переменной (`name`, `surname`, `something`) можно получить через суперглобальные массивы `$_GET` или `$_REQUEST`.

Вот ссылки почитать о них:

- [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php)
- [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.request.php)
- [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php) - тоже пригодиться

2) Если запрос составлен другим образом, то надо получить весь `URL` - это делается как говорит `@klopp - $url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Про массив [`$_SERVER`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php).

Дальше идем по строке и ищем наш `id` и что находится за ним.

```
for($i=0;$i+1<strlen($url);$i++)
{
   if($url[$i]=='i'&&$url[$i+1]=='d')
   {
       //обрабатываем ситуацию
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если вам надо цифру ид, то `$_GET['id']`.

Answer (score 3):

URL "вытаскивается" из `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы просто получил весь url и с помощью [регулярных выражений](http://www.phpfaq.ru/regexp) проверил условие.
Вполне подойдет функция [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: @Hlogeon, Надо помнить, что пока выполняется регулярное выражение, где-то в мире успевает умереть котёнок. )) Посему, если есть возможность, то надо стараться обойтись без регулярок.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

галочку в кружочке не забудьте поставить)

Comment: @cnofss, а это ничего, что вопрос задан более 2-х лет назад и на него уже есть ответы лучше вашего? Да и ваш ответ практически повторяет ответ пользователя @klopp.

Comment: Сейчас, сейчас, тоннель только в 2012 открою.